# Is there a specific name for this formula?

Tags: statistical-significance

I was wondering if there was a specific name for this formula and if it is involved in an established statistical process (like how chi-squared tests are for comparing observation classes or t tests are for distributions without a known population stddev), or if this is an original development from the referenced article author. I wish to understand its usage a bit more is why.

How it is referenced in the article:

> A further test, based on the work of Ellegard and Thomson, was
>   devised to determine "Distinctive Numbers" ... The "distinctive numbers" which result
>   are therefore given the symbol D. This test is in fact finding where x-epsilon is the expected occurrence, x-0 the observed occurrence and x the average occurrence in the grand total. The effect of this is to increase the denominator when the Stowe manuscript uses a word either more often or less often than the average, giving a lower D value and weighting the result so that increased notice is taken of occurrences when abnormalities in the texts coincide.

The formula in question:
$$
D=\sum\frac{[(x_\epsilon-\bar{x}) - (x_0-\bar{x})]^2}{|x_\epsilon-\bar{x}|}
$$

The article where I found it: [Harvey, P. (1970). Stylistic Analysis](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3613854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks something like a $\chi^2$ test, though the denominator is slightly different.

If you run through the (trivial) algebra, the numerator reduces to ($x_\epsilon - x_o)^2$, which is just like the $\chi^2$ test's numerator of $(N_{\textrm{expected}} - N_{\textrm{observed}})^2$. The denominator for a $\chi^2$ test is normally just the expected value ($x_\epsilon$ in your notation). Here, they appear to be adjusting the expected value for each candidate according to its prevalence in their entire corpus. I can see why you'd want to do this pragmatically, but it does mean that you can no longer treat the result as an actual $\chi^2$ value (e.g., for looking it up on a table).

If you didn't want to call it a "distictive number", I suspect you might get away with calling it a "modified $\chi^2$ value" or something like that--I'm not sure it has another name.